# Does a blank space matter? - (bool sent,)

Tags: ether, eth-call, send

In terms of sending ETH from a contract, if only the boolean is needed and the data gets omitted, I always see two different versions.

Some people write it with a blank space (bool sent, ) and some without (bool sent,)

Does it actually matter whether you write it with a space or not?
... and if not, which is the recommended way?

```
function sendETH(address _address) external payable {
    (bool sent,) = payable(_address).call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(sent, "Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style guide says that there should not be a whitespace before a closing parenthesis, but there is always a space after a comma, and I think the specific rule for the comma should take precedence over the general rule for parenthesis, so I would write `(bool sent, )`, it looks clearer and also the formatter in Remix does the same.

It doesn't matter anyway.